# jQuery collapse tab if it is the same selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

Using accordion jQuery I want to `collapse` if now is active selected tab

now if I click on same tab nothing, but if I click on another tab activated tab is changed

[example on jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/harrisonstatham/WvtEw/)

how I can to set inactive(`slideUp`) tab if I click when is active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if it already displaying then hide it:

```
if($(a).css("display") == "block")
  $(a).slideUp('fast');
else
  $(a).slideDown('fast');
```

or use `.is()` to check if it is visible:

```
if($(a).is(":visible"))
   $(a).slideUp('fast');
else
  $(a).slideDown('fast');
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WvtEw/805/)

[FIDDLE USING **is(":visible")**](http://jsfiddle.net/dj8p9wxL/)

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
$(a).slideDown('fast');
```

to this:

```
$(a).slideToggle('fast');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the slide of the accordian is already visible using `:visible`:

```
link.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    $("#accordion div").slideUp('fast');  
    var $target = $(this.hash);
    if (!$target.is(':visible'))
        $target.slideDown('fast');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WvtEw/808/)